# how to bind one thread to one queue? Is it mpsc?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, coroutine, actor

Is it my understanding of actor model, mpmc and mpsc right?

I have seen some code like this before:

```
public enum ProcessorId implements CommandProcessorId {
    AUTH,
    PLAYER,
    PERSIST,
    COMMON;
}


@Slf4j
@Data
public abstract class Command implements Runnable {
    private Queue queue;

    @Override
    public final void run() {
        try {
            if (queue != null) {
                CommandContext ctx = CommandContext.ctx.get();
                ctx.setQueue(queue);
            }

            this.action();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("command execute failed.", e);
        }
    }

    protected abstract void action() throws Exception;
}


public class CommandContext {
    public static final ThreadLocal<CommandContext> ctx
            = ThreadLocal.withInitial(CommandContext::new);

    @Setter(AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
    private Queue queue;

    private CommandContext() {

    }


    public static Queue getQueue() {
        return ctx.get().queue;
    }

}

public interface CommandProcessor {

    CommandProcessorId getId();

    Queue getQueue(long key);

}

public interface CommandProcessorId {

}

@Component
public class CommandRouter implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private final Map<CommandProcessorId, CommandProcessor> processors = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(@Nonnull ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        applicationContext.getBeansOfType(CommandProcessor.class).forEach((name, bean) -> {
            CommandProcessorId id = bean.getId();
            if (processors.containsKey(id)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("processor repeated: " + id + "/" + bean.getClass().getName());
            }
            processors.put(id, bean);
        });
    }


    public void process(CommandProcessorId processorId, long key, Command command) {
        CommandProcessor processor = processors.get(processorId);
        if (processor == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("processor not found: " + processorId + " - " + command);
        }
        Queue queue = processor.getQueue(key);
        if (queue == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("get queue failed: " + processorId + "/" + key + " - " + command);
        }
        queue.append(command);
    }
}

@Slf4j
public class Executor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

    public Executor(int corePoolSize, int maxPoolSize) {
        super(corePoolSize, maxPoolSize, 30L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(), new ThreadFactory() {
            final AtomicInteger n = new AtomicInteger(0);
            @Override
            public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
                String name = "queue-execute-thread-" + n.incrementAndGet();
                log.error("create thread: {}", name);
                return new Thread(r, name);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
        super.afterExecute(r, t);
        ((Command) r).getQueue().resume();
    }
}

public class Queue {
    public static final Executor EXECUTOR = new Executor(16, 16);

    @Getter
    private final long id;
    @Getter
    private final String name;
    @Getter
    private final int capacity;

    private final java.util.Queue<Command> queue;

    private boolean running = false;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private boolean destroy = false;


    public Queue(long id, String name, int capacity) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
    }

    public boolean append(Command command) {
        command.setQueue(this);
        synchronized (this) {
            if (!running && !destroy) {
                running = true;
                EXECUTOR.execute(command);
                return true;
            }
            return queue.offer(command);
        }
    }

    protected void resume() {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (destroy) {
                running = false;
                return;
            }
            Command command = queue.poll();
            if (command == null) {
                running = false;
                return;
            }
            EXECUTOR.execute(command);
        }
    }

}

public class QueueCommitException extends AppException {
    public QueueCommitException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}

public class PlayerIndex implements ExposedIndex {
    @Override
    public Object get() {
        return ProcessorId.PLAYER;
    }
}

@Component
public class PlayerProcessor implements CommandProcessor {
    private final Map<Long, Queue> queues = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @Override
    public CommandProcessorId getId() {
        return ProcessorId.PLAYER;
    }

    @Override
    public Queue getQueue(long key) {
        return queues.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new Queue(key, "player@" + key, 1000));
    }
}


public class CommonIndex implements ExposedIndex {
    @Override
    public Object get() {
        return ProcessorId.COMMON;
    }
}

@Component
public class CommonProcessor implements CommandProcessor {
    private final Queue queue = new Queue(0, "common", 2000);

    @Override
    public CommandProcessorId getId() {
        return ProcessorId.COMMON;
    }

    @Override
    public Queue getQueue(long key) {
        return queue;
    }
}
```

I think it is a combination of actor model with mpmc((Multiple Producer Multiple Consumer)).

For example, each player is an actor,  persist and auth services(see `ProcessorId`) are also actors. In the actor model, there're serveral important factors: address, mail, mailbox. As an actor processes `mail` in its    `mailbox` sequentially, so we don't worry the data race problem in each queue.

For one player(see `PlayerProcessor`):

```
private final Map<Long, Queue> queues = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(); // key is playerId
```

I think the `Long playerId` is `address`, `Queue queue` is a `mailbox`, and `Command command` is a `mail`. If I want to send an `mail`  from other actor to an player(eg. commit some items to player's backpack at midnight in SpringBoot @Scheduled annotated method), the code would be:

```java
public Promise<Void> safeCommit(Player player, LogAction action) {
        Promise<Void> promise = new DefaultPromise<>();
        Queue queue = CommandContext.getQueue();
        if (queue != null && queue.getId() == player.getId()) {
            try {
                commit(player, action);
                promise.setFulfilled(null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                promise.setRejected(e);
            }
        } else {
            GameApplicationContext.getBean(CommandRouter.class).process(ProcessorId.PLAYER, player.getId(), new Command() {
                @Override
                protected void action() throws Exception {
                    try {
                        commit(player, action);
                        promise.setFulfilled(null);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        promise.setRejected(e);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        return promise;
    }
```

This code is somewhat similar to `tell` in Akka:

```java
GameApplicationContext.getBean(CommandRouter.class).process(ProcessorId.PLAYER, player.getId(), 
                                                            new Command() {...});

// akka 
targetActor.tell(message, sender)
```

And I think the code at the beginning is `mpmc` implementation. For example, if 100 players send each request to the server, then there're 100 requests in different player queues and there would be 16 thread at maximum to process these requests. I think the clients who send requests are producers, while the threads that process the logic are consumers.

Since the code uses thread pool not to create a new thread for each `command`, and to avoid shared data race, each queue are locked using `synchronized` keyword to block other threads until the processing thread release the lock.

Therefore, I have the following question:

1. Since queues are detached from one thread and then attach to another, there must be many lock and unlock operations, which result huge cost of thread switching.

   And I've heard some people say that bind one thread to one queue(is it `mpsc` implementation?) are much effective. Since there're limited threads in the thread pool, if once there're large number of players online simultaneously, the threads don't seem to be enough.

   I want to know how to bind one thread to one queue without lock primitives to ensure concurrent safety.

If my understanding or my questions are wrong,  please let me know.  And if you are willing to show your code implementation, I would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time.